# How to tell ReSharper to Auto-Format with one parameter per line

Tags: c#, formatting, resharper

I would like to instruct my ReSharper to format my code so that when initializing objects with parameters, it formats them with one parameter per line if they do not all fit into one line without hitting the limit.

However, the closest I have come with the configuration options I have found still has ReSharper sometimes put two or more parameters into one line, like so:

```
                        new BomColumnHelper("MtlPartNum", "Mtl Part Number")
                        {
                            Style = ColumnStyle.EditButton,
                            CellEditMode = Activation.NoEdit, DefaultWidth = 200,
                            Hidden = true
                        }
```

How I would like this to look instead is:

```
                        new BomColumnHelper("MtlPartNum", "Mtl Part Number")
                        {
                            Style = ColumnStyle.EditButton,
                            CellEditMode = Activation.NoEdit,
                            DefaultWidth = 200,
                            Hidden = true
                        }
```

Is there a way to configure ReSharper to auto-format the code like this? I have already set all the formatting settings that seem to apply to this selection to "Chop if long or multiline".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm running Resharper 2021.2 and the option is deeply wrapped in the options hierarchy:

- Extensions / Resharper / Options
- ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Formatting Style | Line Breaks and Wrapping
- Arrangement of initializers | Max. object and collection initialzier elements on a single line
- Set to 1